# What is the proper way to write 2 if else statements in a function?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use 1 function to control multiple elements effected by scroll. I'm new to coding other than CSS. So Im a little confused on the best way to do this.

```
function scrollFunctions() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("rbuxApp");
  var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
  var head = document.getElementById("header");
  var buttons = document.getElementById("scrollBtnHolder")

  // Add class for header
  if(y >= 4 && head.classList.contains("min-header")) {
    head.classList.add("min-header");
  }
  else {
    head.classList.toggle("min-header");
  };

  // Add class for button
  if(y >= 1000 && buttons.classList.contains("show-scroll-btn")) {
    buttons.classList.add("show-scroll-btn");
  }
  else {
    buttons.classList.toggle("show-scroll-btn");
  };
}
```

Comment: This is some kind of what is proper way to eat food.

Comment: `head.classList.toggle("min-header", y >= 4 && head.classList.contains("min-header"));` and `buttons.classList.toggle("show-scroll-btn", y >= 1000 && buttons.classList.contains("show-scroll-btn"));`

Answer (score 0):

Use second parameter of [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

> add/remove visible, depending on test condition passed as second parameter to the `toggle()`

```
head.classList.toggle("min-header", y >= 4 && head.classList.contains("min-header"));

buttons.classList.toggle("show-scroll-btn", y >= 1000 && buttons.classList.contains("show-scroll-btn"));
```

If the condition evaluates to `true`, class will be added to the element, if condition evaluates to `false`, class will be removed.

```js
function scrollFunctions() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("rbuxApp");
    var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
    var head = document.getElementById("header");
    var buttons = document.getElementById("scrollBtnHolder")

    head.classList.toggle("min-header", y >= 4 && head.classList.contains("min-header"));

    buttons.classList.toggle("show-scroll-btn", y >= 1000 && buttons.classList.contains("show-scroll-btn"));
}
```